# Put a <br> between certain characters

Tags: php, regex

I have a string that follows this predictable pattern:

```
This is a string, it has a comma in it, This is another string, it also has a comma in it, This is a third string, it follows the trend
```

And so on.

Obviously the string represents a list, which is separated by commas. Only, the list's items have commas in them too. The way to determine the beginning of a new item is a Capital Letter.

I managed to match the pattern with this: `[, \p{Lu}]` but I am uncertain of what to do next. If I use `preg_split()` I lose the comma, which is desired, but I also lose the Capital Letter, which is not. The properly preg_replaced string should look like this

```
This is a string, it has a comma in it<br />
This is another string, it also has a comma in it<br />
This is a third string, it follows the trend
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
$result = preg_replace('/, (?=\p{Lu})/u', '<br />\n', $subject);
```

The regex means "Match a `,` and a space, but only if they are followed by an uppercase Unicode letter". That way, the letter doesn't become part of the match itself.

Comment: Tweaked it a little: `$result = preg_replace('/, (?=\p{Lu})/u', '<br />', $subject);` Space to be replaced too and unnecessary newline, which doesn't work correctly, because of the single quotes, I suspect. But thank you, I did't know about lookahead, until you pointed it out.